# F# Use generic type as pattern discriminator

Tags: f#, pattern-matching, discriminated-union

If there's another way to achieve what I'm trying to do below, please let me know. Suppose I have the following sample code

```
type FooBar = 
  | Foo
  | Bar

let foobars = [Bar;Foo;Bar]

let isFoo item  = 
  match item with
  | Foo _ -> true
  | _ -> false

foobars |> Seq.filter isFoo
```

I want to write a generic/higher-order version of isFoo that allows me to filter my list based on all other types of the discriminated union (Bar in this case).

Something like the following, where 'a can be either Foo or Bar

```
let is<'a> item  = 
  match item with
  | a _ -> true
  | _ -> false
```

However, this attempt yields the following error:

> error FS0039: The pattern discriminator 'a' is not defined

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just want to filter a list, then the easiest option is to use `function` to write standard pattern matching:

```
[ Foo; Bar; Foo ]
|> List.filter (function Foo -> true | _ -> false)
```

If you wanted to write some more complicated generic function that checks for a case and then does something else, then the easiest option (that will work in general) is to take a predicate that returns `true` or `false`:

```
let is cond item  = 
  if cond item then
    true
  else
    false

// You can create a predicate using `function` syntax
is (function Foo -> true | _ -> false) <argument>
```

In your specific example, you have a discriminated union where none of the cases has any parameters. This is probably an unrealistic simplification, but if you only care about discriminated unions without parameters, then you can just use the cases as values and compare them:

```
let is case item = 
  if case = item then
    true
  else
    false

// You can just pass it 'Foo' as the first parameter to 
// `is` and use partial function application
[ Foo; Bar; Foo ]
|> List.filter (is Foo)

// In fact, you can use the built-in equality test operator
[ Foo; Bar; Foo ] |> List.filter ((=) Foo)
```

This last method will not work if you have more complicated discriminated union where some cases have parameters, so it is probably not very useful. For example, if you have a list of option values:

```
let opts = [ Some(42); None; Some(32) ]
opts |> List.filter (is Some) // ERROR - because here you give 'is' a constructor 
                              // 'Some' instead of a value that can be compared.
```

You could do various tricks using Reflection (to check for cases with a specified name) and you could also use F# quotations to get a bit nicer and safer syntax, but I do not think that's worth it, because using pattern matching using `function` gives you quite clear code.

**EDIT -** Just out of curiosity, a solution that uses reflection (and is slow, not type safe and nobody should actually use it in practice unless you *really* know what you're doing) could look like this:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection
open Microsoft.FSharp.Quotations

let is (q:Expr) value = 
  match q with
  | Patterns.Lambda(_, Patterns.NewUnionCase(case, _)) 
  | Patterns.NewUnionCase(case, _) ->
      let actualCase, _ = FSharpValue.GetUnionFields(value, value.GetType())
      actualCase = case
  | _ -> failwith "Wrong argument"
```

It uses quotations to identify the union case, so you can then write something like this:

```
type Case = Foo of int | Bar of string | Zoo

[ Foo 42; Zoo; Bar "hi"; Foo 32; Zoo ]
|> List.filter (is <@ Foo @>)
```

Comment: @Thomas: I was trying to avoid having to specify a full predicate every time. Aren't the ifs superflous (ie I could just use let is case item = case = item)?

Comment: @JohannesRudolph Writing `let is case item = case = item` will work as long as you do not have parameters in your DU. For example, it will not work with option type, because `is Some (Some(42))` will not type check.

Comment: Although in case when your DU cases do not have parameters, you can quite neatly write `items |> List.filter ((=) Foo)`, which is probably what you wanted and you don't even need any functions. See edit :-).

Comment: @Thomas: Yeah, that's best in this case. Unfortunately my DU has parameters and I was oversimplifying for this example. Have a much better understanding of the matter now though, which made me realize there's no way I can a generic type into a compile-time-checked pattern match expression.

Comment: @JohannesRudolph I added a more "generic" solution that uses reflection, but that's really an overkill (and it is also slow), so I do not think it should be used :-) but just to see what _might_ be possible.

Comment: It seems useful to have the ability to determine the constructor function a value represents, without the gymnastics and performance penalty of reflection and quotations.

Answer (score 3):

As long as union cases accept the same set of parameters, you can pass a constructor as an argument and reconstruct DUs for comparison.

It looks more appealing when `Foo` and `Bar` have parameters:

```
type FooBar = Foo of int | Bar of int

let is constr item = 
    match item with
    | Foo x when item = constr x -> true
    | Bar x when item = constr x -> true
    | _ -> false
```

In your example, constructors have no argument. So you can write `is` in a simpler way:

```
type FooBar = Foo | Bar

let is constr item = item = constr

[Bar; Foo; Bar] |> Seq.filter (is Foo)
```

Comment: I don't think that using pattern matching in this case is helpful. In fact (and I also did not realize that when writing my first answer), you can just say `let is = (=)` :-).

Comment: It will be more appealing if `Foo` and `Bar` have arguments. You compare by decomposing `item`: `| Foo x when item = constr x`.

Comment: Yes, that makes more sense. In the case with parameters, it is actually useful. In the case without, it is just a fancy implementation of `=` :-)